# Make This Strumming Pattern

Tags: guitar, guitar-pro

Is it posssible to make this strumming pattern in Guitar Pro 7?

With **"Bm"**

Each bar consists of **8 beats**.(8/4)

1. Thumb down stroke
2. Silence (Let ring)
3. Silence (Let ring)
4. Thumb up stroke
5. Palm mute
6. Index finger up stroke (just G,B,High E)
7. Index finger down stroke (just G,B,High E)
8. Index finger up stroke (just G,B,High E)

Comment: Why does the chord matter? I‘d say this pattern is possiple ... on any chord in any key. If you don‘t mind not having the root as basstone ...

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli The **Bm** chord is an example. With this strumming pattern I want to make a progression of Bm,A,G,Bm

Comment: I‘m not sure then ... so you‘re asking whether you can play or notate this pattern with a software like guitar pro?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Yes, create a progression of Bm,A,G,Bm with that strumming pattern in Guitar Pro

Comment: By palm mute, do you mean mute all of the strings or play the chord palm-muted?

Answer (score 2):

In Guitar Pro, if you want to use proper finger notation you'll have to assign each note to a finger. This is because finger labelling is typically reserved for fingerstyle guitar, not strumming. For example:

[image: Image using fingering notation]

This can look pretty ugly. An alternative could be to use the "Text" option (keyboard shortcut: `T`, looks like the letters `TXT` in the Edition Palette), for example:

[image: Image using TXT]

This is a little neater, but still not the best. Anyway, here's what it would look like if you used the `TXT` method:

[image: Image of full score]

I'm not sure how familiar you are with composition, but here are some composing tips:

- Honestly, with strumming I wouldn't recommend specifying which finger you want the player to use as this should be left up to the player. It's up to them what feels most comfortable.
- 8/4 is a weird time signature. I'd recommend using 4/4 and writing these as 8th notes (quavers) - it's much more natural for musicians to read this.
- I've used straight arrows to indicate strumming direction, but you can also use wiggly arrows. Listen in the editor to see what sounds best for you - they're both valid but indicate slightly different strumming techniques.
- The in the dotted half note (minim) means "1.5x the note's length", ie a half note + a quarter note. You can split this out and tie them together if you want.

Comment: "... I wouldn't recommend specifying which finger you want the player to use...." -- for a score intended for other players, I'd agree that this kind of fussiness is silly, and even counterproductive noise in the score. But a valid reason to make such detailed performance notes would be if the OP were trying to record technical details that made it possible for them to play the piece in the way they wanted to; that is, if this is really a note-to-self for the OP.